# Why link both a bank account and a bank card to a PayPal account?

Tags: paypal

I currently have both my bank account and the Mastercard bank card linked to my PayPal account.

I was wondering what is the point of having both, and what'll happen if I remove the Mastercard option: Will all operations keep working, be they purchasing goods from the Net or sending money to friends?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Linking the card is primarily to give you (and Paypal) a fall-back option for funding your spending if your bank account doesn't have sufficient funds to process the charge.  If the bank account has sufficient funds, it will work fine in many cases without a credit card.

If you have both linked (bank and a credit card), Paypal will transfer funds immediately, as Paypal knows it has an option for getting the funds if the bank has insufficient funds.  However, [if you have no credit card linked or remove your only card](https://www.paypal.com/selfhelp/article/FAQ1862):

> If you remove your only card and have a confirmed bank account, you’ll no longer be able to make instant bank payments. Instead they’ll be sent as eChecks, which take 3 to 4 working days to process.

This may not matter in many cases, but it may delay things some.  There may also be services who require immediate payment (and won't support PayPal if it's not immediate).

There may also be some functional limitations.  The one I see is primarily that some services that are geo-location-specific, Spotify for one example, use the credit card to verify that you are in a particular location (in Spotify's case, for licensing purposes).  They don't seem to accept Paypal unless it's linked to a credit or debit card (even if it's verified via a bank account).  I'm not sure if this is common with other services, but it's something to consider.

Comment: Thanks much for the infos. Although my bank account has enough money on it, when using the Android application last night to send money to a friend, PayPal still insisted on using my Mastercard instead  of withdrawing money from my bank account for free, charging a commission for this. I assumed it didn't matter if the PayPal balance is empty, but it looks like it does. I'll remove the Mastercard and see how it goes.